# Calculating the time difference to midnight everyday

Tags: r

I am using a novel approach of using the RFM model for segmenting addiction level of phone app usage. A quick explanation of RFM since it is relevant with the code I wrote: it is a marketing model which R is Recency, how many days since the customer last purchased on a site; F (frequency), how many times did the customer make transactions on a site; M (monetary): average money spent on this site per transaction (total money / frequency). By dividing these scores into different groups you can know which groups are more loyal to your brand, but I want to try it out to measure the addiction of different types of app.

I instead will replace these values with:

R: how many seconds since the user used this type of app before midnight 12:00 PM;

F: how many times did he use this type of app in a day;

M: average duration of this type of app usage;

You can find dput sample data here, sorry that the data only have two users' info, I still don't know how to make a random dput dataset yet:

```
    structure(list(application = c("com.android.calculator2", "com.whatsapp", 
                               "com.whatsapp", "com.android.mediacenter", "com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp", 
                               "com.android.mediacenter", "com.whatsapp", "com.facebook.orca", 
                               "com.whatsapp", "com.android.chrome", "com.google.android.youtube", 
                               "com.tinder", "com.android.vending", "com.android.mms", "com.google.android.youtube", 
                               "com.whatsapp", "com.google.android.youtube", "com.facebook.orca", 
                               "com.huawei.android.internal.app", "com.android.chrome", "com.android.calculator2", 
                               "com.android.server.telecom", "com.android.incallui", "com.whatsapp", 
                               "com.android.mediacenter", "com.android.mediacenter", "com.android.settings", 
                               "com.google.android.youtube", "com.whatsapp", "com.facebook.orca", 
                               "com.android.mediacenter", "com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp", "com.ninegag.android.app", 
                               "com.whatsapp", "com.huawei.android.internal.app", "com.whatsapp", 
                               "com.facebook.orca", "com.android.server.telecom", "com.android.contacts", 
                               "com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp", "com.facebook.orca", "com.whatsapp", 
                               "com.audible.application", "com.facebook.orca", "com.android.vending", 
                               "com.android.mediacenter", "com.audible.application", "com.spotlightsix.zentimerlite2"
), battery = c(99L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 59L, 59L, 86L, 82L, 82L, 78L, 
               78L, 78L, 59L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 21L, 20L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 66L, 66L, 
               66L, 51L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 61L, 15L, 83L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 77L, 77L, 
               76L, 74L, 74L, 68L, 67L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 14L, 42L, 21L, 7L, 49L, 
               47L, 7L), endTime = structure(c(1552937669.979, 1552939304.982, 
                                               1552940267.085, 1552940491.247, 1552927214.751, 1552927358.731, 
                                               1552943502.52, 1552947058.616, 1552947085.757, 1552947640.862, 
                                               1552948140.615, 1552950642.956, 1552950670.904, 1552698488.211, 
                                               1552699286.179, 1552699661.943, 1552694622.527, 1552695838.488, 
                                               1552669634.35, 1552669720.844, 1552669759.436, 1552658315.76, 
                                               1552658392.324, 1552658435.825, 1552826238.709, 1552829407.296, 
                                               1552830394.329, 1552830666.554, 1552834920.948, 1552843002.461, 
                                               1552850435.957, 1552924112.501, 1552924305.967, 1552924485.245, 
                                               1552746587.447, 1552746621.156, 1552746808.486, 1552747504.807, 
                                               1552747525.748, 1552749348.81, 1552749531.786, 1552774429.995, 
                                               1552774593.78, 1552774601.257, 1552765986.942, 1552866265.965, 
                                               1552869582.984, 1552871863.451, 1552863539.106, 1552864201.43, 
                                               1552872500.501), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
session = c(1552929316L, 1552937670L, 1552937670L, 1552940489L, 
            1552926942L, 1552926942L, 1552942385L, 1552947023L, 1552947023L, 
            1552947023L, 1552947023L, 1552947023L, 1552947023L, 1552698280L, 
            1552698280L, 1552698280L, 1552694528L, 1552695704L, 1552669479L, 
            1552669479L, 1552669479L, 1552658249L, 1552658249L, 1552658249L, 
            1552825368L, 1552829142L, 1552830354L, 1552830378L, 1552830378L, 
            1552842287L, 1552849970L, 1552923851L, 1552924111L, 1552924284L, 
            1552745790L, 1552746579L, 1552746579L, 1552747501L, 1552747501L, 
            1552748903L, 1552748903L, 1552774264L, 1552774264L, 1552774264L, 
            1552765953L, 1552865369L, 1552869549L, 1552869549L, 1552862301L, 
            1552862301L, 1552869549L), startTime = structure(c(1552937669.974, 
                                                               1552939288.014, 1552940265.404, 1552940489.402, 1552927083.565, 
                                                               1552927349.671, 1552943488.401, 1552947031.581, 1552947061.03, 
                                                               1552947572.997, 1552948109.636, 1552948146.197, 1552950662.47, 
                                                               1552698481.19, 1552699269.439, 1552699288.018, 1552694548.992, 
                                                               1552695764.75, 1552669520.073, 1552669719.309, 1552669722.031, 
                                                               1552658293.438, 1552658391.914, 1552658392.34, 1552826236.588, 
                                                               1552829400.281, 1552830375.788, 1552830660.017, 1552834299.004, 
                                                               1552842297.013, 1552850071.788, 1552924108.617, 1552924282.513, 
                                                               1552924479.884, 1552746579.19, 1552746590.718, 1552746807.361, 
                                                               1552747501.668, 1552747507.62, 1552749347.688, 1552749522.781, 
                                                               1552774269.867, 1552774430.015, 1552774600.383, 1552765963.791, 
                                                               1552866265.186, 1552869577.804, 1552871854.773, 1552863054.623, 
                                                               1552864194.888, 1552872479.38), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                                               ), tzone = ""), user_id = c(10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 
                                                                                           10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 
                                                                                           10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 
                                                                                           10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 
                                                                                           10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10161L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 
                                                                                           10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 
                                                                                           10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L, 10162L), 
categories = structure(c(6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
                         1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                         6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
                         1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("communication", 
                                                                                         "games & entertainment", "lifestyle", "news & information outlet", 
                                                                                         "social network", "utility & tools"), class = "factor"), 
date = structure(c(17973, 17973, 17973, 17973, 17973, 17973, 
                   17973, 17973, 17973, 17973, 17973, 17973, 17974, 17971, 17971, 
                   17971, 17971, 17971, 17970, 17970, 17970, 17970, 17970, 17970, 
                   17972, 17972, 17972, 17972, 17972, 17972, 17972, 17973, 17973, 
                   17973, 17971, 17971, 17971, 17971, 17971, 17971, 17971, 17971, 
                   17971, 17971, 17971, 17973, 17973, 17973, 17972, 17973, 17973
), class = "Date"), duration = structure(c(0, 17, 1.7, 1.8, 
                                           131.2, 9.1, 14.1, 27, 24.7, 67.9, 31, 2496.8, 8.4, 7, 16.7, 
                                           373.9, 73.5, 73.7, 114.3, 1.5, 37.4, 22.3, 0.4, 43.5, 2.1, 
                                           7, 18.5, 6.5, 621.9, 705.4, 364.2, 3.9, 23.5, 5.4, 8.3, 30.4, 
                                           1.1, 3.1, 18.1, 1.1, 9, 160.1, 163.8, 0.9, 23.2, 0.8, 5.2, 
                                           8.7, 484.5, 6.5, 21.1), class = "difftime", units = "secs")), row.names = 162574:162624, class = "data.frame")
```

I am having trouble with the Recency part as I am not familiar with handling time type data. So far I can only figure out this, which does not calculate the daily RFM, but only the last day of the whole dataset.

```
df_RFM <- df_data %>% 
 group_by(user_id) %>% 
 summarise(recency=as.numeric(as.Date(endTime)-max(endTime)),
           frequency=n_distinct(categories), monetary= sum(duration)/n_distinct(categories))
```

Same as the frequency and monetary, it is caculated based on the whole dataset but I need them to be caculated on a daily basis. In a nutshell, a dataset which contains each user's daily app RFM, divided by each category, looking like this (just an example, not real value):

```
 user_id     date       recency    frequency   monetary    categories
  10161  2019-03-15     21040 sec       5         109.7 utility & tools
  10161  2019-03-15     77538 sec       1         181.6   Communication
  10161  2019-03-16     12345 sec       4         123.5   games&entertainment
  10161  2019-03-16     77538 sec       1         181.6     communication
  10162  2019-03-15     21040 sec       2         109.7   utility & tools
  10162  2019-03-15     77538 sec       3         181.6   Communication
  10162  2019-03-17     12345 sec       12        123.5   games&entertainment
  10162  2019-03-17     77538 sec       2         181.6     utility & tools
```

By reading this you can get information like: user 10161 on 03-15, used utility & tools 5 times, with an average of 109.7 seconds. His last time of using utility & tools was 21040 ago before midnight.

any suggestion is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want it per `user_id`, `date` combination, you should `group_by` both variables. In addition, you probably want to use `difftime` for time differences so that you can better control what units things are being returned in.

```r
df_RFM <- df_data %>% 
    group_by(user_id, date, categories) %>% 
    summarise(recency=difftime(lubridate::ceiling_date(max(endTime), unit='day'), max(endTime), units='secs'),
                        frequency=n(), monetary=mean(duration))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Probably my problem statement isn't clear enough, but I am also interested in the categories of the apps, there should also be a categories in the final dataset, like this:           
`user_id         date               recency            frequency         monetary     categories
10187      2019-02-213432.0490000248           3          22.3333333333333     communication`

but when I ran the code the categories are not in the dataset, I tried to group them with categories but did not work. Could you please elaborate on how can we add it inside?

Comment: Do you want a column which has the distinct categories for each id-date pair or do you want a separate row for each id-date-category combination?

Comment: I just updated the problem statement , please take a look... i know it might be complicated but thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: I just updated my answer. Since there will only be one category in each row, the `n_distinct(categories)` parts no long work. Instead, I just subbed them out for the number of occurrences in each combination (`n()`) and `mean` instead of the old calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I've read your request, I think I would do it in this way:

```
    df_rfm %>%
  # add the endTime as date
  mutate(date_end =ymd_hms(endTime )) %>%
  # group by user, type and date, due it seems you need
  group_by(user_id, categories, date ) %>% 
  # here RFM
  summarise(       
   # here max date and midnight, to understand the steps: midnight
   # should be 00:00:00 of the day after +days(1)
   # comment/delete them for the final result
    max_d = max(date_end),
    midnight = ymd_hms(paste0(format.Date( max(date_end),"%Y-%m-%d")," 00:00:00"))+ days(1),
    # recency is the difference between max date_end and 00:00:00 of that date_end
    recency = (ymd_hms(paste0(format.Date( max(date_end),"%Y-%m-%d")," 00:00:00"))+ days(1))-max(date_end)

    # frequency is the distinct of categories
    ,frequency = n_distinct(categories)
    # monetary is the average of duration by categories
    , monetary = = mean(duration))
 # A tibble: 21 x 8
# Groups:   user_id, categories [8]
   user_id categories            date       max_d               midnight            recency         frequency monetary      
     <int> <fct>                 <date>     <dttm>              <dttm>              <time>              <int> <time>        
 1   10161 communication         2019-03-15 2019-03-15 18:07:14 2019-03-16 00:00:00  5.879444 hours         1  114.3000 secs
 2   10161 communication         2019-03-16 2019-03-16 02:21:26 2019-03-17 00:00:00 21.642778 hours         1   45.1000 secs
 3   10161 communication         2019-03-17 2019-03-17 20:20:35 2019-03-18 00:00:00  3.656944 hours         1  357.2333 secs
 4   10161 communication         2019-03-18 2019-03-18 23:20:40 2019-03-19 00:00:00 39.333333 hours         1   37.7625 secs
 5   10161 games & entertainment 2019-03-16 2019-03-16 02:27:41 2019-03-17 00:00:00 21.538611 hours         1  223.8000 secs
 6   10161 games & entertainment 2019-03-17 2019-03-17 16:02:00 2019-03-18 00:00:00  7.966667 hours         1  621.9000 secs
 7   10161 games & entertainment 2019-03-18 2019-03-19 00:10:42 2019-03-20 00:00:00 23.821667 hours         1 2496.8000 secs
 8   10161 lifestyle             2019-03-17 2019-03-17 14:46:34 2019-03-18 00:00:00  9.223889 hours         1   12.7500 secs
 9   10161 lifestyle             2019-03-18 2019-03-18 22:11:42 2019-03-19 00:00:00  1.805000 hours         1    6.6000 secs
10   10161 lifestyle             2019-03-19 2019-03-19 00:11:10 2019-03-20 00:00:00 23.813889 hours         1    8.4000 secs
# ... with 11 more rows
```

All the values are by type of app, user and date.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation! When I run the code I got completely different answer from you, the date is using and the frequency is all set to 1....however, I realized that my problem statement was not clear enough and probably confused you , I just updated it, could you please take a look? :)